# Output forms and responses to PDF in Cognito Forms

Tags: cognito-forms, pdf

We are an Adobe FormCentral customer. We use the forms as permit applications on our website. These permit applications then get imported (pdf) into the permit management system. We need the same functionality, as the permit application with the user inputted information becomes public record.

Is this possible in Cognito Forms? And if yes, how can I do it?

Answer (score 1):

There are a range of answers to this question:

1. You can print and Save to PDF when managing entries, and then use this PDF in the permitting system.
2. If you really want the PDF to match an official paper form today, you can use a services like [Zapier](http://www.zapier.com) to connect your forms to [WebMerge](http://webmerge.me) to generate PDF forms.  You can do this today with our JSON post feature and we are about to release an official [Zapier app](https://trello.com/c/ApSYn6gl).
3. We are working on native PDF/DOCX merging as part of [Cognito Forms](https://www.cognitoforms.com).  We are very excited about this feature and know it will be very important to our customers.  We expect to have this in place in a few months.  You can track our progress on this feature on our [Idea Board](https://trello.com/c/6lmmtMMy).

We know full and well that the first option is not sufficient for some organizations, especially government organizations with official forms that must be filled out.  Also, the Zapier to WebMerge route is less than ideal (and pricey).

This is why we have always planned to support native merging of form data to PDF and DOCX files.  This feature was already on our Next Up list before Adobe announced the "retirement" of FormsCentral, but hearing from their devoted customers has just reinforced the importance of this for us.

Comment: Cognito Forms now supports a configurable Save as PDF option when managing entries, and you can also allow users to download a PDF copy from the confirmation page and/or receive a PDF copy in confirmation emails.